# Method not visible help?? Java

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, invisible

I have an issue with a method not being visible to another class and I can't figure it out. 
I have a Shopping_Basket class that has a Merchandise list (Merchandise is a class). I'm trying to have the Merchandise list in the Shopping_basket class to reach a getItemCost method in the Merchandise class. However i get an error that the method is not visible... I can't figure out what's wrong:

```
public class Shopping_Basket { 
   private List<Merchandise> basket;
   public List<Merchandise> getList() {
    return basket;
}

   public Shopping_Basket() {
    basket = new ArrayList<Merchandise>();
   }
   public double getTotalCost() {
    double j = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < this.getList().size(); i++){            
         j += basket.get(i).getItemCost();
    }
    return j;
}
```

Here's the Merchandise Class:

```
public class Merchandise {
private String item_name;

private int item_cost;

public Merchandise(String name, int cost) {
    this.item_name = name;
    this.item_cost = cost;
}
public String getItemName() {
    return item_name;
}

public double getItemCost() {
    return item_cost;
}
```

So error in the getTotalCost() method and it says the getItemCost() is not visible... help?

Comment: The method should be accessible. Make sure to do a clean build of everything.

Comment: This is not the cause of your problem but in `Merchandise`, you declare `item_cost` as an `int` yet return it from a method that has a return type of `double`.

Comment: A small thing that is not causing your issues suns java style guild discourages underscores in java names. So most people would expect ShoppingBasket and itemCost not Shopping_Basket and item_cost.

Comment: How are you running the program?  From an IDE?  Command line?

Comment: I don't understand how you are initializing the constructor of Merchandise class, when you use it

Comment: If you are using Java 1.5 and later use `for(Merchandise m : basket) { j += m.getItemCost(); }` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is fine, and actually compiles and executes fine. See below and cross check if you did everything right (I have just added a `main()` method in order to execute your code):

```
$ cat > Merchandise.java
public class Merchandise {

        private String item_name;

        private int item_cost;

        public Merchandise(String name, int cost) {
                this.item_name = name;
                this.item_cost = cost;
        }

        public String getItemName() {
                return item_name;
        }

        public double getItemCost() {
                return item_cost;
        }
}

$ cat > Shopping_Basket.java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Shopping_Basket {

        private List<Merchandise> basket;

        public List<Merchandise> getList() {
                return basket;
        }

        public Shopping_Basket() {
                basket = new ArrayList<Merchandise>();
        }

        public double getTotalCost() {
                double j = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < this.getList().size(); i++) {
                        j += basket.get(i).getItemCost();
                }
                return j;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                Shopping_Basket sb = new Shopping_Basket();
                System.out.println(sb.getTotalCost());

        }

}

$ javac Shopping_Basket.java

$ java Shopping_Basket
0.0
```

So, as I said and as you can see, the code is good. For the compiler, at least because there are a couple of things to point out:

- In `Merchandise`, `item_cost` is an `int`, but `getItemCost()` returns a `double`
- The name of your class `Shopping_Basket` should be modified to something like `ShoppingBasket`

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong, this code should compile and actually does compile on my computer.
Please try to clean your project in your IDE, and compile the whole project again.

Comment: This is really more of a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The classes are correct. The method is public so it's visible.
Maybe is a problem of setting of classpath or importing of the classes.

```
public class Merchandise {
private String item_name;

private int item_cost;

public Merchandise(String name, int cost) {
    this.item_name = name;
    this.item_cost = cost;
}

public String getItemName() {
    return item_name;
}

public double getItemCost() {
    return item_cost;
}
```

}

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

import java.util.List;

public class Shopping_Basket {
    private List basket;

```
public List<Merchandise> getList() {
    return basket;
}

public Shopping_Basket() {
basket = new ArrayList<Merchandise>();
```

}

```
public double getTotalCost() {
    double j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.getList().size(); i++) {
        j += basket.get(i).getItemCost();
    }
    return j;
}

public void addMerchandise(Merchandise m){
    basket.add(m);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Merchandise m1 = new Merchandise("prova", 11);
    Merchandise m2 = new Merchandise("prova2", 13);

    Shopping_Basket sb = new Shopping_Basket();

    sb.addMerchandise(m1);
    sb.addMerchandise(m2);

    System.out.println(sb.getTotalCost());
}
```

}